# Automator keystroke not working with Zero digit

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an automator script that should make the browser go full screen and scale it back to default size using command + 0. Fullscreen works, but the keystroke with the 0 is ignored.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}        
    keystroke "0" using {command down}
end tell
```

I tried:

```
 keystroke "0" using {command down}
 keystroke 0 using {command down}
 keystroke {29} using {command down}
```

all ignored.

Comment: after tell system event and before keystroke, you must tell your browser and make it activated. Then keystroke will be sent to your browser as expected.

Comment: you mean return input. yes I have that. This is just the tell part of the script. The command+F executes, but not the command+0

Comment: What is your browser and what command+0 should do ? (I tried Safari, but command+0 does nothing)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a timing issue. (Eric posted the same thought as I was writing this!) :)

You can add a delay:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
        delay 1
        keystroke "0" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

But in my testing, you can also reverse the order of operations. It will work and won't require the delay.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "0" using {command down}
        keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll reiterate what pbell said and offer the working code for Finder, as I'm not sure how your particular app works:

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell application "Finder" to activate
   keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
   delay 1
   keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
end tell
```

The important part there is that we activated Finder first, so the keystrokes are being sent to the proper application.

Also important, depending on the use case, is enabling the Accessibility privilege for your application in "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "Privacy" -> "Accessibility"